# Dynamic Conditional Check

Tags: c#

I am working C# and Couchbase.
We have class for all the docs in couchbase.
And while getting data the json is serialized to the class object.

The requirement is i should have common method which should receive the key to fetch document from the couchbase and other conditions
(e.g) consider this document is in couchbase

```
{
 name : "sfk",
 qualification : "BE",
 age : "24",
 hobbies : ["Cricket", "Chess","Music"]
}
```

and i need to get the document only when "sfk" has a hobby "Cricket" and age is greater than 20.

Right now this we are doing in business layer by fetching the document and validating objCollection.age > 24 like dat.

Now what i need is a method should receive these conditions and process and returns data.

Something like,

GetData("SFK").GT(o=>o > 24).AND(o => o.hobbies.Contains("Cricket");

```
 public dynamic Get<T>(string key, Predicate<T> funcPredicate )
    {
        try
        {
            var d = _objClient.GetJson<T>(key);
            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<T>();
            predicate.Or(p => p.Name == "CBR");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // ignored
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I tried something like that. But didn't know how to use that Predicate to make validation.

How to achieve this. Please help.

Comment: I don't understand the implementaion. The type parameter `T` seems to be used only for the argument `funcPredicate`, which in turn is not used in the function body.

Comment: @Codor yeah thats a mistake. I actually didn't know how to do that.

Comment: Why would you not pass that criteria into couchbase as part of the query?  What if you had 2 million rows that satisfied "SFK"? Downloading all 2 million rows and comparing age will be slow.

Comment: No "SFK" is the key and value is Json. So it wont be more than one row in "SFK"